# is_page() not working with archives?

Tags: menus, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am creating a dynamic menu and in my foreach loop I am running a is_page using the page title:

```
<li class="<?= (is_page($tlp->post_title) ? 'active' : '');?>">
</li>
```

This works fine for pages that are actually created in the WP admin. But for other post types that rely on the archive it doesn't work.

So I have a 'team' post type and a archive-team.php page which uses the data.

When on that page, I have no way of checking if the page is currently active?

I came across is_archive() but that doesn't do as expected. Just returns if it is a archive.

I also loop through the pages to create this menu, so I have a blog page set up and just do a check in the default template to include the archive if its the blog page.

Any help?

Comment: This won't fix your issue, but you should pass the ID instead of the title: `is_page( $tlp->ID )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_page( $tpl->ID ) || is_single( $tlp->ID )` which will cover posts, pages and custom post types.

For the archive link, use `is_post_type_archive( $post_type )`. If you need it highlighted for single posts of the same type, add `|| is_singular( $post_type )`